# "gcc --version" can't find gcc despite having g++-5 and gcc-5 installed?

Tags: apt, gcc, c++, g++

I want to have gcc-5 because I want c++14 support. So I removed the previous versions of gcc; gcc-4.8 and gcc-4.9 and installed gcc-5 and g++-5. But now when command `gcc --version` it replies:

```
The program 'gcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

On the other hand, if I command `sudo apt-get install gcc-5`, I get the reply `gcc-5 is already the newest version`. But if I command `sudo apt-get install gcc` it always tries to take gcc-4.8.

Why is this behaviour? How can I ensure I get gcc-5 when command `sudo apt-get install gcc`.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, `/usr/bin/gcc` is usually a symbolic link to the default version of gcc for your system - which you've removed. You can either create a symbolic link manually, or invoke the desired version of gcc explicitly i.e. `gcc-5 --version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is a bad to update libraries from a testing PPA, unless you know what you're doing.**

You're not getting any response for `gcc --version` because you don't have the `gcc` program with version 5.x available in current apt-repositories. The package-manager (here `apt`) have maintained two different packages for the same program but different versions 4.x and 5.x.

You can't get `gcc-5` when you type `sudo apt-get install gcc` because it will try to get package named `gcc` not `gcc-5` from the list of repositories defined by `apt`. Instead I would suggest you to get `gcc-5` and then replace it with `gcc` or replacing an alias in `~/.bashrc` file.

If you want to replace your gcc-5 with gcc you can try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/beci/2a2091f282042ed20cda) link. Or mainly

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
```

A **less recommended** option would be to add

```
alias gcc='gcc-5
```

in you `~/.bashrc`. It will use `gcc-5` when you use it from terminal and any other calls to `gcc` won't trigger `gcc-5`.

Comment: I strongly advice to restrain from that PPA. updating C libraries from a testing PPA is a very ugly idea

Comment: Add the warning in your answer please.